# There was no endpoint listening at https://localhost:44302/Service7.svc that could accept the message

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I created a `WCF` service hosted on IIS and posted with HTTPS. When I launch my client code, I got error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: There was no endpoint listening at https://localhost:44302/Service7.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

However, when I launch `https://localhost:44302/Service7.svc` in the browser, I can get "You have created a service." like the picture shown below:

[image]

Those two url are exactly the same and I am confused why I am getting this error.

My client `app.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpsBinding_IService7">
                    <security mode="Transport" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://localhost:44302/Service7.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpsBinding_IService7" contract="ServiceReference1.IService7"
                name="BasicHttpsBinding_IService7" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

My service `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Too long to read it all but I can't find the word Certificate here. And notice the red strikeout in the address in your screenshot. It's not 'just working'.

Comment: I assumed you overwrite secured port in your IIS to 44302 and assigned your untrusted certificate because by default https protocol is bonded to port 443? Is your client calling the service through service reference?

Comment: Follow this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36705/simple-steps-to-enable-HTTPS-on-WCF-WsHttp-bindi

Comment: Did u tried the service without https ? If it works fine then we can be sure that there is no issue in service. Further, try the steps mentioned here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556232(v=vs.110).aspx